# Submit is not functioning

Tags: jquery, triggers, internet-explorer-9, submit

I have this code. It works with google chrome and `firefox` but I don't understand why it fails with IE 9. I think there is a problem with `jquery` submit or trigger. I searched a lot on the web and I didn't find a solution. It Seems to be hard to show the problem because sometimes it works but very rarely.

```
$(function() {
$("#dialog").dialog("destroy");



$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 200,
    width: 300,
    modal: false,
    buttons: {
        'Se connecter': function() {
            $(".ajax").trigger('submit');
        },
        Retour: function() {
            $("#dialog").dialog('close');
        }
    },
    close: function() {

    }
});

$(".ajax").submit(
    function(e) {
        var login_username = $("#login_username").val(),
         login_password = $("#login_password").val();

    //alert(login_username + " pass  " + login_password+ " domaine " +domaine_apside);

    $.post('Login',{login_username:login_username,login_password:login_password});
    location.reload();
    return false; // Pour empêcher le submit vers la page 'action'
});


$('#connect')
    .button()
    .click(function() {

    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
});
});
```

Comment: Could you clarify "fails"? What happens, exactly?

Comment: IN fact nothing, "login_username" and "login_password" are null.

Comment: What is "#connect" ? If it is a submit button, you need to return false or use e.preventDefault() or bind to the submit event of the form

Comment: It works in chrome and firefox. "#connect" is a button which calls the jquery dialog

Comment: Try document.location.reload() instead of location.reload().

Comment: still the same problem with "document.location.reload()"

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$('#connect').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
});
```